# how to compare two maps and return valid key-value pair map

Tags: java, spring, collections

```
    Map<String, String> hash_map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(); 

    Map<String, String> new_hash_map = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();

    hash_map.put("AA", "Geeks"); 
    hash_map.put("BB", "4"); 
    hash_map.put("CC", "Geeks"); 
    hash_map.put("DD", "Welcomes"); 
    hash_map.put("EE", "You"); 

    new_hash_map.put("BB", "4");
    new_hash_map.put("EE", "You");
    new_hash_map.put("FF", "Me");
```

hash_map contains some keys and values, new_hash_map also conatins some keys and values.
My requirement is to compare the new_hash_map with hash_map and return valid key-value pair map of new_hash_map

Comment: Use `new_hash_map.keySet()` to get a `Set<String>` of all the keys in `new_hash_set`; iterate over that set, look up the values for each key in both `hash_map` and `new_hash_map` until you find a key that has the same value in both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [stream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#stream) with Java 8 to get the intersection between maps in this way:

```
Map<String, String> intersection = hash_map.entrySet().stream()
                .filter(map -> (new_hash_map.containsKey(map.getKey())
                        && new_hash_map.get(map.getKey()).equals(map.getValue())))
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(map -> map.getKey(), map -> map.getValue()));
```

This code uses filter to get values into map where `key` and `value` are the same. I.e. the intersection between two maps.

And value of `intersection` variable is: `{EE=You, BB=4}`.

Also I've added `new_hash_map.put("CC", "Me");` to ensure `CC` key is not output.